# Using Itertool to create all possible combinations on several columns with constrain on sum() of one column

Tags: python, python-itertools

I used Itertool module in Python to output all possible combination of multiple columns in a data frame. But I did the process separately for each column. I wonder if there is a way to do the process in one shot for all the columns and ignore the combination with sum > target value.

Here is the example of my process and expectation

Given data frame

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 10 | 2 | 0.5 |
| y | 20 | 3 | 0.2 |
| z | 15 | 6 | 0.1 |
| i | 5 | 2 | 0.5 |

Output table: the number of rows will be n! = 4! and I want the process exclude combinations when sum[col B]>20

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 10 | 2 | 0.5 |
| y | 20 | 3 | 0.2 |
| z | 15 | 6 | 0.1 |
| i | 5 | 2 | 0.5 |
| x,y | 30 | 5 | 0.7 |
| x,z | 25 | 8 | 0.6 |
| x,i | 15 | 4 | 1.0 |
| y,z | 35 | 9 | 0.3 |
| y,i | 25 | 5 | 0.7 |
| z,i | 20 | 8 | 0.6 |

.....

Here is my current code: I combined chain with combination to improve the performance

```
def powerset(iterable):
    l = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(l,r)for r in range(1, 4))
```

and then repeat the process for each column and join the lists together and create a table (note, A is a list)

```
for i, combo in enumerate(powerset(A), 1):
    Capcomb = list(powerset(A))
```